# cannot install python packages in rstudio project environment

Tags: python, r, github, rstudio

I primarily use rstudio for running python scripts. I'm interested in trying out rstudio's github integration. Unfortunately, I cannot get python libraries installed. `!pip install pandas` for example returns the error `sh: pip: command not found`. When i try installing from terminal I get that same error. I guess pip is not installed in this environment (I tried installing pip with `python get-pip.py` but `sh: python: command not found` I guess it indicates python is not installed, which is just wrong bc i can access it)?

My google searches have not uncovered enough for me to go on. At best, I think this is related to the issue of installing python libraries in virtual environments but I'm not sure what to do with that information so any direction/help is appreciated.